# 16.04 unable to shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

An Ubuntu 16.04 LTS instance failed to shutdown. The shutdown was initiated from the Unity interface. The graphical interface became unresponsive. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> provided a login prompt. I was able to login and run the `shutdown --poweroff now` command but it reported that it would be running a destructive operation and failed to obey the command as per some policy. I could use some suggestions for debugging this further.

Comment: I found the following content reported by journalctl when experiencing a failed shutdown attempt:

Comment: `polkitd(authority=local)[949]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.75, object path /org/gnome/Policy
systemd-logind[808]: System is powering down.
systemd[1]: Requested transaction contradicts existing jobs: Transaction is destructive.
systemd-logind[808]: Failed to send delayed message: Transaction is destructive.
systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

Comment: $ systemctl list-jobs
    JOB UNIT                                  TYPE  STATE  
    390 systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service start running
    389 dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device          start running 
    388 dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap            start waiting
    
    3 jobs listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the inability to shutdown only occurred when a suspend/resume had been performed during the session. However, `ps aux | grep suspend` did not give any results. It appears that the shutdown issue was related to another issue in 16.04 LTS whereby the swap partition encryption is not working. I filed the details in Launchpad Ubuntu [Bug #1594035](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1594035). Ultimately, I just disabled swap and deleted the swap partition. Encrypted swap is broken and it is interfering with suspend/resume/shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I see it too. The problem started after allowing nvidia updates. While I backtrack on that, I will tell you the only solution I've found

Run

```
ps aux | grep suspend
```

you should see a root-owned suspend process. Then kill that process:

```
sudo kill -9 xxxx
```

where xxxx is the number of the job.

Warning: the PC will suspend immediately when you do this, and then when you try to wake up, you are likely to be in an incoherent situation and it is best to reboot.